# xlC and Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed

Tags: c, aes, powerpc, xlc, altivec

I'm trying to compile a source file on PPC64-LE. I'm using the xlC compiler and the compile is failing. GCC accepts the program, so I'm not really sure what the cause of the problems are.

Here's the command line:

```
$ xlc test-p8.c -qarch=pwr8 -qaltivec -o test-p8.exe
```

Here's the compile error:

```
"test-p8.c", line 113.52: 1506-324 (S) "int" cannot be converted to "vector unsigned int".
"test-p8.c", line 120.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 121.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 122.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 123.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 124.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 125.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 126.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 127.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 128.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
"test-p8.c", line 130.15: 1506-068 (S) Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed.
```

Here's the relevant part of the source file. The source file is a reduced case for [another problem](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2017-09/msg00044.html), and it its [available on GitHub](https://github.com/noloader/AES-Power8).

```c
$ cat -n test-p8.c
   ...
    12  typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
    13  typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
    14  typedef vector unsigned char uint8x16_p8;
    15  typedef vector unsigned int uint64x2_p8;
   ...
    76  __attribute__((aligned(16)))
    77  uint8_t ks[176] = {
    78      0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x9,  0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c,
   ...
    89  };
   ...
   113  uint64x2_p8 block = (uint64x2_p8)vec_vsx_ld(0U, (const uint8_t*)plain);
   ...
   118  block = vec_xor(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld(0U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   ...
   120  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 16U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   121  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 32U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   122  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 48U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   123  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 64U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   124  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 80U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   125  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 96U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   126  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld(112U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   127  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld(128U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   128  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld(144U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
   129
   130  block = __builtin_crypto_vcipherlast(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld(160U, (const uint8_t*)ks));
```

`__builtin_crypto_vcipher` is a GCC built-in, and IBM states [xlC supports it](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248171.pdf).

Line 118 is like all the other lines show above, but it does not trigger a warning or error.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

On PPC64-LE, a lot of effort went into unifying the interface for the vector builtins between GCC and XL.  The two teams worked together on adding a consistent interface to the ABI document.  You can find it here:

[HTML](https://openpowerfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/resources/leabi), [PDF](http://openpowerfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/resources/leabi/leabi-20170510.pdf)

The new vcipher function that's part of the ABI is vec_cipher_be, which xlC supports.

Note that part of the reason for the new function is that the types accepted by the some of the old GCC crypto functions would have endianess issues.

Answer (score 1):

The [redbook you linked to](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248171.pdf) is about "Performance Optimization and Tuning Techniques for IBM Power Systems Processors Including IBM POWER8" and is not compiler specific. It includes information about compiler support on POWER8, including the XLC and GCC compilers.

In section 7.3.1, page 149 of the redbook (page 171 if you're using the PDF page advancer), the following support is stated:

- **GCC**: `vector unsigned long long __builtin_crypto_vcipher (vector unsigned long long, vector unsigned long long)`
- **XL C/C++**: `vector unsigned char __vcipher (vector unsigned char, vector unsigned char)`

If you're compiling with GCC, you should use `__builtin_crypto_vcipher`, and if you're compiling with XLC, you should use `__vcipher`.

Comment: Thanks. *"The redbook you linked to is about...[not built-ins]"* - it sounds like I copied/pasted the wrong browser tab URL. I should have used the compiler manual or online docs. I don't recall which one anymore.

Comment: Please let us know if you notice a place where our docs need changing. [Here's a link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVZZ_13.1.5/com.ibm.xlcpp1315.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/bif_crypto_aes_vcipher.html) to this topic in our online docs.

Comment: Thanks again. In this case, I think the compiler diagnostic should be improved. The compiler should have specifically identified `__builtin_crypto_vcipher` as a function without a prototype or an undeclared function. Telling me `int` cannot be converted to `vector` is not very helpful.

Comment: In the latest (unreleased) version, the diagnostic has been improved to say:
`test-p8.c:138:10: error: use of unknown builtin '__builtin_crypto_vcipher' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, (uint64x2_p8)vec_ld( 16, (const uint8_t*)ks));`. Also, it looks like you are not using the latest released version. You can [try it](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/572f1638-121d-4788-8bbb-c4529577ba7d/entry/Download_XL_C_C_for_Linux_V13_1_5_Community_Edition_a_no_charge_fully_functional_production_use_compiler?lang=en) for free.

Answer (score 0):

> `Operation between types "vector unsigned int" and "int" is not allowed`

I think I tracked this down. xlC does not know the function `__builtin_crypto_vcipher`, so the compiler assumes the function accepts `int`'s as arguments or returns an `int` (I'm not sure which at the moment). I believe the equivalent GCC message is something about a missing declaration and assuming an `int` return.

Later, the unknown function takes a vector instead of an int:

```
__builtin_crypto_vcipher(block, ...)
```

or, it assigns an `int` to a vector:

```
block = __builtin_crypto_vcipher(...)
```

When I switched to xlC's builtin `__vcipher` the issue went away.

I don't know why the docs state xlC accepts GCC  builtin's.